# How do you talk about a boring, repetitive sound?

Tags: translation

There are a lot of repetitive songs where I work. How do I mention how repetitive the music is, and convey that I dislike it to an all Japanese staff. Can I use 重ね重ね?

Comment: are you asking how to say “a boring repetitive sound” or are you asking for some Japanese term that means that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good word for this concept is [ワンパターン](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/239098/meaning/m0u/)な(曲), which is a wasei-eigo term that exactly means "boring and repetitive" or 繰り返しが多くて退屈な(曲). Saying only 繰り返しが多い曲 does not necessarily mean the song is bad.

重ね重ね is a fairly stiff word that is usually used in business settings, and it means a similar troublesome/unfortunate event happening again and again. 重ね重ねの不幸, 重ね重ねのお詫び, 重ね重ねのお願い, etc. 重ね重ねの曲 means nothing to me.

Answer (score 0):

There are many people who complain about the music played inside stores.
Below are some of the ways they describe it:

店内のBGMがうるさくて気分が悪くなる

音楽の音量が大きいので、音を下げてください

うるさい大音響のＢＧＭはイライラして

スーパーや家電量販店のテーマ曲の延々ループも嫌です

店員さんは耳や精神に異常を感じないのでしょうか。

TVのCMで使ってる曲を延々流し続けてる。

ボリュームも大きいので、買い物しているあいだずっと耳に入り、店舗を出た後も頭にメロディーが残り続けるという人も少なくないと思われます。

http://komachi.yomiuri.co.jp/t/2015/0731/723583.htm
http://komachi.yomiuri.co.jp/t/2016/1005/780313.htm
https://sirabee.com/2015/04/17/26677/
http://www1.nhk.or.jp/asaichi/hattatsu/torisetsu/cat_hearing.html